# Form of adjoint matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, adjoint-operators

Let $\left\langle x,y\right\rangle$ be an inner product (in a real space). Then, there is a matrix $S$ symmetric s.t. $$\left\langle x,y\right\rangle=x^t Sy.$$

I want to have the form of the adjoint of $A$, i.e. the matrix $B$ s.t. $$\left\langle Ax,y\right\rangle=\left\langle x,By\right\rangle.$$

I did as follow,
$$\left\langle Ax,y\right\rangle=(Ax)^tS y=x^tA^tSy=x^t\left(S^tA\right)^t y\underset{G\,\mathrm{sym}} {=}x^t\left(SA^t\right)^ty.$$

How can I get something like $x^t S By$ ? Bye the way, does my computation will prove the existence or not ?

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close. $S$ will not only be symmetric, but also positive deinite, this means that it will also be invertible.

So the two following expressions are equivalent:

$$\left\langle Ax,y\right\rangle=x^tA^tSy=x^tSBy=\left\langle x,By\right\rangle$$

$$A^tS= SB  $$

And as $S$ is invertible.

$$ B = S^{-1}A^tS$$